# How to add multiple case in sql

Tags: sql

I want to add multiple cases in single line. In other words in below example if first item is NOT NULL and second item is equal to 1 then output should be 1 else 0. How can I do it?

```
 MatchbyCatalog= (case when ISNULL(pc.ProductID,0)  and tc.RawMatch=1) then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: NO, its not working since it is  incomplete. I am just giving an idea if first item is not null and second item is 1 then output would be 1

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
CASE WHEN pc.ProductID IS NULL and tc.RawMatch=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

You misunderstood `ISNULL()` , it's a function that replaces the value if it's NULL, it's not a condition . You were looking for `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

That's all you need.

```
MatchbyCatalog= (case when ISNULL(pc.ProductID,0)=1  and tc.RawMatch=1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score -1):

when you say both I think you mean pc.ProductID and tc.RawMatch...
 I have not you're entire sql query so I have to guess.
 You have multiple solutions :

1. Nearly ss you have wrote when pc.ProductId = 1 and tc.RawMatch=1 then 1 else 0 :

   MatchbyCatalog= (case when ISNULL(pc.ProductID,0)=1  and tc.RawMatch=1) then 1 else 0 end)
2. You could also use a trick : 1 * 1 should be 1 and 1 * 0 =0 so you could write (if tc.Rawmatch is a boolean sort of with values 0 or 1) :

   MatchbyCatalog= ISNULL(pc.ProductID,0) * tc.RawMatch

Answer (score -2):

```
   case when   {Condition} then   {result} 
        When   {Condition} then   {result} 
        Else    {result}
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Comment: @JonathanMee if yu are not able to understand any code then what can we do. its a self explanatory code